# Input field value not returning the value i expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Javascript and HTML**

---

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var inputMessage = $("#inputMessage");
    var sendButton = $("#sendButton");
    console.log(inputMessage.value); //->undefined
    inputMessage.value = "hello";
    console.log(inputMessage.value); //->"hello"
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <title>Chat de Hernan</title>
 <!--jquery-->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
 <!--bootstrap-->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="input-group">
  <input id="inputMessage" class="form-control" type="text" value="goodbye" placeholder="Escriba aqui">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
   <button id="sendButton" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
  </span>
 </div>
 <!--js-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem i'm having is that the values **undefined**   and **"hello"** are different form the value **goodbye**.

```
<input id="inputMessage" class="form-control" type="text" value="goodbye" placeholder="Escriba aqui">
```

How is this possible? The *value="goodbye"* statement points that the input has a "goodbye" value, but javascript says that it's values are undefined and "hello", respectibely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining  `var inputMessage = $("#inputMessage");` makes `inputMessage` jQuery element which has method `val()` to get/set element value.

So instead of 'inputMessage.value' use `inputMessage.val()` or `inputMessage.val('hello')` to set the new value.

Comment: I dont understand why the negatives on everyones answers. You identified the root of the problem and explained it

Comment: Me neither. Maybe someone of the others can leave comment and give feedback what was wrong in their opinion. Maybe I can improve the syntax, but I think how I explained is understandable.

Answer (score 2):

It's the attribute you need to target:

```
inputMessage.attr('value')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mark_c/ged56amh/

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're getting the input as a jQuery object, but you're using JavaScript functions. Instead, change `value` to `val()`. Also, don't forget to close your `.ready`.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var inputMessage = $("#inputMessage");
    var sendButton = $("#sendButton");
    console.log(inputMessage.val()); //->undefined
    inputMessage.val("hello");
    console.log(inputMessage.val()); //->"hello"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <title>Chat de Hernan</title>
 <!--jquery-->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
 <!--bootstrap-->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="input-group">
  <input id="inputMessage" class="form-control" type="text" value="goodbye" placeholder="Escriba aqui">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
   <button id="sendButton" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
  </span>
 </div>
 <!--js-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```